# does insertOrThrow() of class SQLiteDataBase autocommit the data?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, commit

My insert code looks like this

```
public void insertInTable(float x, float y, float z, int timestamp){

    try {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("x_val", x);
        values.put("y_val", y);
        values.put("z_val", z);
        values.put("timestamp", timestamp);

        db.insertOrThrow(DBHelper.tableName, null, values);
        Log.d(Constants.CUSTOM_LOG_TYPE, "Inserted successfully");

    }
    catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.d(Constants.CUSTOM_LOG_TYPE, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And its called from the following piece of code:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

     ...values retrieved from event ....
     ...the inserted into db

    if (conditions met) {
        //****here the data is inserted****
        dbHelper.insertInTable(x, y, z, (int) timeInMillis);
    }
}
```

This code inserts the data fine in the database, and when the db file is exported, the data inserted is present.

**My question is how is the data being exported present without the committing the transaction ?**

I tried looking into the documentation of [insertOrThrow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertOrThrow(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)), but it doesn't mention anything with regards to auto-commit.

autocommit is set to false , which I know because when I try inserting using execSQL(), the data is not exported without explicitly committing the transaction.

There is no use of transaction, commit or even setAutocommit(true).
How is the code working ?  Am I missing something here ?

Comment: Only if you were actually using a **transaction**. Which you are **not**.

Comment: @ModularSynth - so without a transaction, insert queries are automatically committed ?

Comment: They are **executed immediately** as the code flows. And they don't need to be committed. And that's why transactions are necessary to encapsulate a batch of instructions which have to be executed **all or none**.

Answer (score 0):

The [SQLite documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) says:

> No changes can be made to the database except within a transaction. Any command that changes the database (basically, any SQL command other than SELECT) will automatically start a transaction if one is not already in effect. Automatically started transactions are committed when the last query finishes.